# Restrict Access to a specified folder

Tags: asp.net

How can I restrict access to a specific folder? For example I have a folder that Authenticated users can upload different files in. The problem is that every user can access the files via the URL in the browser.

I don't use ASP.NET login controls for authenticating and role memberships, I have written a login page and roles my self via code behind.